# why does Comparable modify the original data whereas Comparator does not in Collection framework

Tags: java, collections, comparator, comparable

In Collection framework ,
I am aware Comparable provides single sorting sequence 
whereas 
Comparator provides multiple sorting sequence
But I am unable to understand how one interface modifies the original data whereas the other does'nt ?

Comment: What makes you think Comparable modifies the original data? Are you referring to some specific sort method?

Comment: i am sorry, but can you please give explanation in a proper way..?

Comment: none of them modify anything (at least they shouldn't), just tell which object is "bigger" and which one is "smaller". If a `Comparator` or `compareTo()` modifies an object, it is flawed

Comment: Comparable do not sort anything, it only states that a class implements compareTo method.

Comment: http://www.javatpoint.com/difference-between-comparable-and-comparator - when i was trying to understand the difference between the two, (point 2 in the above link says so..)

Comment: Most of the statements are false or are poorly explained. For example Comparable "affects" the class because it forces you to implement the method "compareTo". It's up to you if you change your object properties on invoking that method, but that makes no sense.

Comment: @Sarronya that link is not working.  Getting 404 and 503 errors.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yes, it does.

Comment: Seems to be hit or miss... works sometimes, other times returns 404 or 503.  I would ignore that resource as it is very poorly written.  Always refer to the official Javadoc

Comment: You should study this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html and delete that other link from your favorites.

Answer (score 3):

`Comparable` does not do anything, it's an interface. It forces your object to implement the method 'compareTo'. That allow the object to be compared with another object.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

`Comparator` does not do anything, it's another interface. It forces your object to implement the method 'compare'. That allow the object to compare two other objects. Note the difference: to be compared and to compare.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

This link explains Object Ordering interfaces very, very well. With examples and everything.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html